# What am I supposed to pass to scrollToEndOfDocument(_:)?

Tags: swift, cocoa, webkit

I’m trying to get a WKWebView to scroll down automatically when its content changes. I added this function to my `WKNavigationDelegate`, which is a subclass of `NSViewController`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Finished loading web view.")
    webView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)
}
```

It crashes:

```
-[WKWebView scrollToEndOfDocument:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001a07e0
```

I guess `self` is not what I should be passing to `scrollToEndOfDocument`. I also tried to pass `webView` or `nil` instead, with the same result. **What value should I pass?**

---

N.B. I tried `self` because [Apple’s docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsresponder/1532690-scrolltoendofdocument) say:

> **Declaration**
>
> func scrollToEndOfDocument(_ sender: Any?)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> sender
>
> Typically the object that invoked this method.

Comment: (I deleted my answer for now since it's for `WebView` and not `WKWebView`.)

Comment: (Undeleted with JavaScript stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do it via JavaScript:

```
let script = "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script)
```

---

This is for old-school WebView; leaving for posterity:

Try calling scrollToEndOfDocument: on the WebView's main frame's document view:

`webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)`

(What you pass in as sender shouldn't matter and has no bearing on the error you're seeing.)

Comment: I tried that, but there seems to be no `mainFrame` property in WKWebView. There is a `frame` property, but that one does not have a `frameView` property…

Comment: Oh, whoops; WKWebView, not WebView. IIRC you have to scroll a WKWebView with JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, WKWebView has a `scrollView` property…editing.

Comment: Argh, that's iOS-only. You might have to go the JavaScript route.

Comment: There is an `enclosingScrollView`, but in my case it is `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be the scroll view wrapping the WKWebView, but not the WKWebView's scrolling itself. I'm going to delete my answer for now and hopefully I or someone else will get back to you.